# Need to show a default selection in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set a default selection within a javascript file.  I found all sorts of ways to create a default selection within the HTML file, but we do not have access to the HTML of the generated page unfortunately.

```
var lAudSel = ["YES", "NO"];
config.updateFieldsLocation = [//no comma after last entry
        ["Finance_Master", "bool3", "Select for Audit", "list", lAudSel, false],
        ["Finance_Master", "date4", "Audit Closed Date", "date", "", false],
        ["Finance_Master", "memo3", "Audit Findings / Comments", "textarea", "", false]
        ];
```

I'm looking to set "Yes" as the default.
I'm new to javascript so I'm hoping that this is something that is not overly complicated.

Comment: What do you mean by "default selection" in a JavaScript file? Please clarify what you are asking. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Default selection? what HTML tag are you talking about?